# Equivalente ao window.showModalDialog para o Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Ola, necessito de uma forma equivalente ao window.showModalDialog para abrir como modal e esperar o retorno dela para continuar o fonte, quando dou um open ele fica assíncrono do meu site e não funciona em conjunto.

ps window.showModalDialog funciona no IE

Answer (score 1):

Olá, de acordo com a documentação da Mozilla essa feature já é obsoleta e foi retirada do Chrome e do Firefox.

Você pode utilizar agora a tag `<dialog>`.

**Trecho retirado da própria documentação**

**HTML**

```
<!-- Simple pop-up dialog box, containing a form -->
  <dialog open id="favDialog">
    <form method="dialog">
      <section>
        <p><label for="favAnimal">Favorite animal:</label>
        <select id="favAnimal">
          <option></option>
          <option>Brine shrimp</option>
          <option>Red panda</option>
          <option>Spider monkey</option>
        </select></p>
      </section>
      <menu>
        <button id="cancel" type="reset">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
      </menu>
    </form>
  </dialog>

  <menu>
    <button id="updateDetails">Update details</button>
  </menu>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
  var updateButton = document.getElementById('updateDetails');
  var cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancel');
  var favDialog = document.getElementById('favDialog');

  // Update button opens a modal dialog
  updateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    favDialog.showModal();
  });

  // Form cancel button closes the dialog box
  cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    favDialog.close();
  });
})();
```

Documentação: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog